# How to pass both JavaScript variables and checkbox results in submit form to controller in laravel 6.x

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

I get stuck in finding the way to pass JavaScript variables and some checkbox results from submit form to controller. Could you please tell me the way I could get all values from the request in controller. All your help is appreciated.

Here is my blade:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form_input" action="#">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="success">
            <td class="text-right">Node Profile:</td>
            <td>
              <select id="node_id" name="node_id" class="form-control" data-placeholder="choose node">
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-right">Overall</td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_id[]" value="Overall" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-right">History</td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_id[]" value="History" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
      <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btn_Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="printFile"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I am using select2 to load data of equipments that appear in dropdown, then here is my code js to load and get id of element after selecting from dropdown:

```
$('#node_id').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  var node = e.params.data;
  alert(node.id);
});
```

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given code? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I have aldready got id of element from dropdown that store into node.id, but I have still not found the way to pass it to controller in laravel